# Attaching properties and methods at runtime in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

What are the performance implications of attaching methods and properties at run time using dynamic features, as described in [this blog post](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2009/09/systemdynamicexpandoobject-similar.html)?

What are the practical uses of ExpandoObject?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the true benefits of ExpandoObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject)

Answer (score 10):

Well, you're not *really* attaching methods and properties to the object. Not as far as the CLR is concerned. You're just adding entries into a dictionary, and when the `ExpandoObject` implementation of `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` is asked for the property value (or asked to execute the method) it will act accordingly.

Performance is obviously going to be slower than statically bound access to methods/properties, but the DLR is pretty nippy. My personal worry isn't performance so much as the lack of type safety - a typo can easily screw your code up without the compiler spotting it.

My personal advice is to only use dynamic typing in C# 4 where it gives a very clear benefit... which I expect to be relatively rare (like unsafe code).

Uses for `ExpandoObject`? Not that many, IMO - mostly when talking to other dynamic languages.

Comment: Whoa, this begins to look like prototype-based programming. Besides that, could it be used to emulate [per-assembly] base class injection?

Comment: Relatively rare?! You sir, are not a Ruby programmer :)

Comment: @Paul: Indeed... because we're talking about C#, rather than Ruby. As a basically statically typed language, I believe it will be relatively rare to turn C# into a mish-mash of static and dynamic typing. If you want to use dynamic typing extensively, use IronRuby or IronPython...

Comment: Thanks Jon. I should then rephrase what ruby can achieve using dynamic features that c# can't

Comment: @Web2: I suggest you ask that in a different post... and it's a topic I'm supremely unqualified to talk about, being a statically typed guy at heart :)

Comment: I _was_ a statically-typed guy at heart, until I was smitten by the beauty of JavaScript. :) Since that time, I've long-lamented C#'s static nature.

Answer (score 2):

`ExpandoObject` relates to the DLR, and is primarily related for playing between C# and a dynamic language (perhaps IronPython); however, more generally this type of property-bag object can be useful when the schema of your types is only known at runtime, perhaps based on database data / configuration data. Perhaps an example of the "inner platform" anti-pattern, but it is useful **in specific scenarios** to attach properties at runtime. Of course, for purely CLR usage (i.e. no DLR callers) you can do this a lot more simply just with an indexer and dictionary:

```
obj["Name"] = "Fred";
string name = (string) obj["Name"];
```

For data-binding purposes, even with this you can achieve full data binding using custom property descriptors, via `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`.

Or for a simple example: consider `DataTable`... this is *in part* what you can do here (again, in static-typed code): (untested example)

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
DataRow row = table.Rows.Add("Fred");
```