# Android.Os.Bundle equivalent on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm creating my own handler method and I want to know how to implement a Bundle parameter that is optional.

In Android it would look like

```
public bool updateUI(int mode, Bundle... params)
{    
    switch (mode)
    {
      case 0: return doStuff(params.getString("Name"));
      default: break;
    }
}
```

This is not covered in the [migration guide](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/windows-phone-guide-for-android-application-developers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to use **Named and Optional arguments** in .NET Framework and in Windows Phone as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx
Or you can use the **params** keyword fore passing arbitrary number of arguments:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=VS.100).aspx

Edit: not sure, how the Bundle actually works, but it looks like a generic container for data. You might try to use **dynamic** type and the **ExpandoObject**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.95).aspx

```cs
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.Data = "data";
d.Result = 42;

return d.Data;
```

[What are the true benefits of ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject)

Comment: Upvote but no accept given because it only answers half the question. Despite bundle can be emulated using params object[] I don't think it is a good idea, and it doesn't provide the functionality Bundle gives.

Comment: Could you tell us why its not a good idea and what additional functionality Bundle provides ?