# How to create Dynamic objects in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, variables, object

I was working on javascript before.

In javascript, I do this to create dynamic object and assign properties to it.

```
var house = new object();
house.kitchen = 1;
house.bedroom = 2;
house.livingroom =3;
```

How to do the same stuff in C#?

Comment: This question is a bit too basic to fit the StackOverflow format.  It's probably a good idea to search for a basic C# tutorial and come back if you have any specific questions.  To start you off, you want to create a `class`, and use this to create an object with `new ClassName()`.

Comment: Exacly like that. Not a single change needed, except for `new house()`. In all seriousness, please go read a basic tutorial. We're here to help with problems and explain them, not provide a step by step tutorial of a language.

Comment: If you are already asking how to create objects then read this first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Aside the dynamic object, c# objects should be considered the equivalent of Classes ..yes we call them objects because at the base everything in c# is an object but in reality we do new Class()

Comment: @Robert That isn't quite right.  An object is an instance of a class - a class was used to create it and a class defines its structure and behaviour, but it isn't a class.

Comment: Yeah i know, but in js you can go defining stuff inline like var house = {}; and house.kitchen = 1; whereas in c# you first have to define your object (class) before you can call new() on it, this is similar to creating a function and calling new() on it, it becomes a class in js. Ok we also have anonymous functions in c# like var house = new { kitchen = 1 }; ..but now i think he's gonna be confused -:)

Comment: Hi All, I have a basic idea of C# and I did some work on it in the past. But in recent times, I very much concentrated on J Script and now I confuse and use same concepts in C#. Anyway I got answer from this thread, I was looking for the same way as J Script to create dynamic object in C#. So I need to use `dynamic house = new ExpandoObject();` to create dynamic objects in C#. Thanks to every one and very special thanks to Rodrick Chapman.

Comment: You could always use a dictionary like this, which makes it behave pretty similarly to Javascript. You can't say `house.kitchen`, but you can say `house["kitchen"]`, which is also true in Javascript. I know it's not the same as defining a class and all that, but it's handy if you're quickly storing values that are just going to be converted to Json and passed back to an Ajax call.
`Dictionary<string, object> house = new Dictionary<string, object>();
house["kitchen"] = 1;
house["bedroom"] = 2;
house["livingroom"] = 3;`

Answer (score 5):

in C# there is something called `dynamic` that you could use

```
dynamic house = new ExpandoObject();
house.Kitchen = 1;
house.Bedroom = 2;
house.Livingroom =3;
```

but if I am new to c# that is not were I would start, `dynamic` has very specific uses, typically in more advanced situations. What you really should be looking at is Classes and objects. C# is a static language, and dynamic is there just to give it a bit more flexibility.

Comment: +1. `var house = (dynamic)new object()` is another option if one likes `var` or even `var house = new {kitchen = 1, bedroom = 2, livingroom =3 };` (but as you've pointed out better to use strongly typed object).

Comment: -1 This code doesn't do what's advertised. It will compile but once you try to set one of properties like that you'll get a `RuntimeBinderException`.

Comment: @RodrickChapman good point, I was being to careless with the code sample, my main point was not really about dynamic but rather about the static nature of C# verses javascript. But still, good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you're looking for something like the [ExpandoObject](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx&ei=f8NxUo7wM9LfkQfR3oDADQ&usg=AFQjCNGS6aoNF_6loEmAt3eFFcI1FuHHVA&sig2=r6bH87t-W-4Pz-O3duanGw&bvm=bv.55617003,d.eW0) in C#. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject) for details on how to use it. Basically, it allows you to add properties to objects at runtime in a manner similar to Javascript. Please note, however, that idiomatic C# doesn't make much use of it.

The analogous C# code for your JavaScript example would be something like this:

```
dynamic house = new ExpandoObject();
house.kitchen = 1;
house.bedroom = 2;
house.livingroom = 3;
```

Comment: Will this dynamic work in visual studio background??

Comment: Is there any special library I need to include in visual studio-08 to use this dynamic feature? Right now it couldn't identify dynamic.

Comment: @Powered - `Dynamic` is a C# 4.0 feature which shipped with Visual Studio 2010. The latest version of the Express Edition of Visual C#, which you can get for free, does include that feature.