# Dictionary to anonymous object

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary collection, string, int. I want convert this dictionary to anonymous object with properties that are collection keys and anonymous object propertie's values are dictionary values. Is it a way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried doing anything?

Comment: But why? Why it has to be anonymous type? I'm missing how that will be useful

Comment: What would you use it for, that you can't use the dictionary for (even easier)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Dynamic objects in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697506/how-to-create-dynamic-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I habe a layer that works with object properties and with their values.

Comment: I dont want rewrite the layer, so I am looking for a way to make a object. I thought I can make with ling. And I see it is possible only with a more code around.

Comment: LINQ anonymous objects are defined at compile time, but this Q would require it to happen at runtime. The answer here is to either stick with a dictionary of name-value pairs or `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
var keyVals = dict.Select(kv => new { Key = kv.Key, Value = kv.Value });
```

But i can't imagine a use case for this. Why do you prefer the anonymous type over the already available dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```
from x in mydictionairy select new { anonymousKey = x.Key, anonymousValue = x.Value}
```