# list of a dynamic class returned by web service not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, web

I'm using `.NET 4.0` and i was trying to create and return a list of `DynamicObject()` from a `.asmx` web service

I copied the dynamic class implementation from [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and i call it `Test()`

**Web Service**

[image]

the service doesn't break it just return this

[image]

i was expecting :

```
<test>
  <name>joe</name>
</test>
```

*what am i doing wrong and is this is the right way for creating a dynamic class properties for web services*

Comment: The class that's in the link is a `DynamicDictionary`, is that what your `Test` class is?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem you're facing is that `DynamicDictionary` isn't serializable. You'll need to implement the `ISerializable` interface. However, it seems to me that you'd be better off just using a list of anonymous types, so something like this:

```
Dim x As New List(Of Object)
Dim y As New With { name = "joe" }
x.Add(y)
Return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject).

If that still doesn't serialize, ExpandoObject implements the IDictionary interface so you could easily make a `List<IDictionary<object, object>>` (sorry, don't know the VB syntax for nested generics) and create your `y` as normal. Then cast `y` to `IDictionary` before adding to the list.