# More elegant or efficient way to access object properties?

Tags: c#, .net

I am coming from JavaScript and trying to better understand working with object in C#. I have some simple code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass firstObj = new MyClass();
        firstObj.Number = 6;
        Console.WriteLine(firstObj.Number);

        object secondObj = doResults();
        string getString = secondObj.GetType().GetProperty("resultsString").GetValue(secondObj).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(getString);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static object doResults()
    {
        ResultsObj newResults = new ResultsObj();
        newResults.resultsString = "Here is my string";

        return newResults;
    }

}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class ResultsObj
{
    public string resultsString { get; set; }
}
```

In the first part of Main(), I create an object, add a property, set a value and then access and display that value. Its all pretty straight forward.

In the second part of Main(), I call the doResults() method, which creates an object a string property.

My questions is this line:

```
string getString = secondObj.GetType().GetProperty("resultsString").GetValue(secondObj).ToString();
```

It seems so involved to me. Is that really the proper/most efficient way to access the properties of the returned object?

Comment: Why return `object` and not `ResultsObj`? you are losing all type safety here.

Comment: Maybe that's the root of the problem. Like I said, coming from JavaScript, I'm used to just throwing objects around with little complexity, so my C# approach could be wrong.

Comment: In your case, a simple cast would work: `((MyClass)ResultsObj).resultsString`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental difference between C# and JavaScript is that C# is a strongly-typed language. In your `main` method you did not "add a property", you set the value of an existing property. The reason you're having so much trouble is that your reference variable is not of the correct *type*.

A *type* is a collection of properties and methods (a blueprint) for an object instance. This is similar to JavaScript except that in JavaScript you can add properties and methods at run-time and in C# you cannot, you are limited to what is available when the code is written (except for ExpandoObject which is a more advanced concept). The compiler will only let you access the properties and methods that are defined by the *type* of the variable being used to make that reference. When you return `object` from your method you are saying "the caller of this method can only access the properties and methods of an `object`".

So basically you need to decide what properties and methods you want the consumer to be able to access (i.e. the *type*). In this case your method creates an instance of `ResultsObj` and returns it, so the return type should be defined as `ResultsObj`.

```
public static ResultsObj doResults()
{
    ResultsObj newResults = new ResultsObj();
    newResults.resultsString = "Here is my string";

    return newResults;
}
```

Now your calling code knows that what is it getting back is a `ResultsObj` can can access the properties and methods of that type.

```
ResultsObj secondObj = doResults();
Console.WriteLine(secondObj.resultsString);
```

It all comes down to *types*. To reiterate, the compiler is only going to let you access properties and methods of the *type* defined by the reference variable.

BTW, you could also write the second block of code as:

```
var secondObj = doResults();
Console.WriteLine(secondObj.resultsString);
```

This may seem confusing, especially coming from a JavaScript background where `var` means something different. In this case C# is doing *implicit typing*. Because the method `doResults()` is defined as returning a `ResultsObj` the variable `secondObj` is implicitly typed as such. If you tried to write the following code it would not compile because the implicit typing already decided that `secondObj` was a `ResultObj` and you cannot assign a number to a variable of type `ResultsObj`.

```
var secondObj = doResults();
secondObj = 1; // This would cause a compiler error
```

Comment: ... and if you want to actually add properties, you should look into `dynamic` or [`ExpandoObject`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1653046/11683).

Comment: While var is an option and does work, I find it better to use the actual object type (in this case ResultsObj) instead of var.  This makes the code more readable by a human trying to come in later or who didn't originally write it.  Otherwise they must go to the doResults() definition to find out what its returning.

Comment: @Wolfie: I think the use of `var` is a personal choice. I happen to prefer it. I do all my development in Visual Studio so I just have to hover over `doResults()` to find out the return type and Intellisense gives me all the available properties and methods so for the most part I really don't care a lot about the type, I just care what properties/methods I can access. Use what you want, there is no right or wrong.

Answer (score 5):

No, using reflection is for sure not the most efficient way. But more important, it's also not the most readable way. Write compile-time type-safe code.

Instead of returning `Object` you should return the right type `ResultsObj`:

```
public static ResultsObj doResults()
{
    ResultsObj newResults = new ResultsObj();
    newResults.resultsString = "Here is my string";

    return newResults;
}
```

then it's easy, readable, safe and efficient:

```
ResultsObj secondObj = doResults();
string getString = secondObj.resultsString;
```

If you can't change the type and you have to use `Object` you can [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) it to the right type:

```
object secondObj = doResults();
ResultsObj resultObj = (ResultsObj) secondObj;
string getString = resultObj.resultsString;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# we have type safety so use it whenever you can. So instead of returning an `object`, return the type you are using, for example:

```
public static ResultsObj doResults()
{
    ResultsObj newResults = new ResultsObj();
    newResults.resultsString = "Here is my string";

    return newResults;
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
ResultsObj secondObj = doResults();
secondObj.resultsString = "blah";
```

Another alternative (and I only mention here because it can be useful in *certain circumstances*, so don't code like this by default) is to use the type `dynamic`. This removes all type checking but means you need to be careful about your code:

```
dynamic secondObj = doResults();
secondObj.resultsString = "blah"; //this will work
secondObj.NonExistantProperty = "blah"; //this will compile but fail at runtime
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `dynamic` also means Intellisense won't work, so its very easy to get typo's and casing issues that won't come up until runtime.

Answer (score 3):

1.Return a `ResultsObj` and not just an `object`:

```
public static ResultsObj doResults()
{
    ResultsObj newResults = new ResultsObj();
    newResults.resultsString = "Here is my string";

    return newResults;
}
```

2.call the method with a correct left hand side:

```
ResultsObj res = doResults();
Console.Write(res.resultsString);
```

P.S.: The left hand side can be var(compiler feature) like in js:

```
var res = doResults(); 
Console.Write(res.resultsString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
public static object doResults()
```

to:

```
public static ResultsObj doResults()
```

then:

```
string getString = secondObj.resultsString;
```