# C# - Append value to new object

Tags: c#, object

I would like to know if exists, in C#, a way to add a value to an object created like this:

```
object myObject = new { a = "First", b = "Second" };
```

Can I add a new field like 'c' to myObject (after the declaration row I mean)?
I've searched on doc, but I wasn't able to find anything to do this.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. How can I do that?

Thank you very much for you help!

Best regards,
Andrea

Comment: ExpandoObject? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject

Comment: Alex beat me to it but the Expando object is probably what you want.

Comment: See Khaja Minhajuddin's answer, it may help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It is important you understand what this syntax means. First of all, `new { a = "First", b = "Second" }` creates an instance of an *anonymous type* with the specific properties you assign. This already answers your question - if an object is created *this* way, you can't "expand" it. Also the cast to `object` is mostly useless, because you lose the access to the properties (use `var` instead of `object` for `new { ... }`, that infers the type as the actual anonymous type you have created).

As for the general question how to expand an object dynamically with new properties, the answer is straightforward - use [*ExpandoObject*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();
myObject.a = "First";
myObject.b = "Second";
myObject.anything = 42;
//etc.
```

If you treat the instance as `dynamic`, every property set/get is treated as a dynamic call, and the binding is done at runtime. *ExpandoObject* allows adding any number of additional properties at any time. If you want to access all properties, cast it to `IDictionary<string, object>`.