# How to return a dynamic object list from web api in c#

Tags: c#, json, api

I Have an object

```
public class GeneralResponseClass
{
    public int ErrorCode { set; get; }
    public string Date { set; get; }
    public String ErrorMessage { set; get; }

    public List<dynamic> Data = new List<dynamic>();
    public bool Success { set; get; }
    public GeneralResponseClass()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

in my API Function i want to return the object

```
[HttpGet]
public GeneralResponseClass Get()
    {
        GeneralResponseClass generalResponseClass = new GeneralResponseClass();

        generalResponseClass.ErrorCode = 0;
        generalResponseClass.ErrorMessage = "";


        generalResponseClass.Success = false;



        generalResponseClass.Data.Add(new
        {
            Name = "User 1",
            Email = "User1@user.com"
        });

        generalResponseClass.Data.Add(new
        {
            Name = "User 2",
            Email = "User2@user.com"
        });

        return generalResponseClass;
    }
```

in the response i get don't get the List

```
 {
   errorCode: 0,
date: "06/01/2020 16:32:12",
errorMessage: "",
success: false
}
```

Why The List Data dont return?

Comment: In `.Net Core` it is Possible.

Comment: Anonymous types are just syntactical sugar. When compiled, a class is generated for it but your application has no scope of this type other than at compile time. Its the same as if you were to use `List<object>`. The JSON serialiser doesn't have any type information to reflect thus nothing returns.

Comment: Please post your API serializer settings if you have defined any. My guess is, you defined it as a field and may be serializer settings are preventing to deserialize it. Try making it a property instead of Field.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return any collection with `anonymous` object. You can use `ExpandoObject` which is simillar to `anonymous`. You can also create a custom class for your type of object since they have the same properties in your case (at least in the template).

You can check for more on `ExpandoObject` here: [What are the true benefits of ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject)

Comment: IMHO, I don't think its issue with dynamic objects. Because in our API, there are dynamic objects returned without any issue.

Comment: I meant anonymous, my bad

Comment: Agree, dynamic is bad but you did not answer the OP's question on why unable to deserialize. you showed alternative instead.

Comment: "How to return a dynamic object list from web api in c#" I guess that's OP's question

Comment: That's fine as long as you have helped OP.

Comment: I am able to see Data in my test API response meaning anonymous type or dynamic is not an issue here. So only I said.