# Add property to dynamic object .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I probably want too much, but my scenario is

```
public dynamic CreateConfigObject(JobConfigurationModel config) {
    dynamic configObject = new { };

    configObject.Git = new GitCheckout {
        Repository = config.Github.Url
    };

    return configObject;
}
```

Of course, it fails on `configObject.Git` since this property does not exist. I want to be able to add any number of properties at run time, with out any beforehand knowledge of number and names of properties;

Is such case possible in C# at all, or my ill JavaScript imagination starts to hurt me? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create dynamic properties in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947241/how-do-i-create-dynamic-properties-in-c)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`dynamic` allows loosely-typed access to strongly-typed objects.

You should use the `ExpandoObject` class, which allows loosely-typed access to an internal dictionary:

```
dynamic configObject = new ExpandoObject();

configObject.Git = new GitCheckout {
    Repository = config.Github.Url
};
```

Comment: ExpandoObject, now my favorite object of .NET :)

Comment: Do not overuse `ExpandoObject`.  Don't abandon compile-time type-safety unless you really need to.

Comment: Actually found a Skeet-Link to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394117/attaching-properties-and-methods-at-runtime-in-c-4-0/1394134#1394134